# How to pluralize and display inside the parentheses?

Tags: html, ruby

I need to display pluralized review count inside the parentheses (1) Review
When I add parenthesis to pluralize method, it returns (1) Reviews instead

```
<%= link_to pluralize("(#{@appointment_type.reviews.eligible.count})", "Review"), appointment_type_path(@appointment_type, anchor: "reviews"), class: "link-muted" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
pluralize("(#{@appointment_type.reviews.eligible.count})", "Review")
```

you can use

```
pluralize(@appointment_type.reviews.eligible.count, "Review").sub(/(\d+)/, "(#{$1})")
```

[Pluralize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize) method expects the 1st argument to be a number (see its code by the link). That's why passing a string such as "(1)" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [`String#pluralize`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb#L33) that Rails define.

```
# Define this somewhere.
amount_of_eligibles = @appointment_type.reviews.eligible.count

<%= link_to "(#{amount_of_eligibles}) #{'Review'.pluralize(amount_of_eligibles)}", articles_path, class: "link-muted" %>
```